# MariaDB Compare 2 tables and delete where not in 1st (Large Dataset)

Tags: database, algorithm, memory, mariadb, large-data

As part of a uni project, I am using MariaDB to cleanse some large CSV's with an algorithm and am using MariaDB 10.5.9 due to the size.

The data is 5 columns with date, time, PlaceID, ID(not unique and repeated), Location
It is a large dataset with approx 50+ million records per day, in total over 1 week 386 million records.

I started to run the algorithm over each day individually and this worked well, the whole process taking between 11 and 15 minutes.

When trying to run over the 7 days combined I have some significant impact on performance.
Most elements work, but I have 1 query which compares values in ID with a list of known good id's and deletes any not in the known good.

`DELETE quick FROM merged WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM knownID) ;`

On a daily table, this query takes around 2 minutes (comparing 50 million against 125 million known good, both tables have indexes to speed up the process on the ID columns on each table.

Table size for merged data is 24.5GB and for known good is 4.7GB

When running across the whole week, I expected around 7 times as long (plus a bit) the query took just under 2 hours? How can I increase this performance? I am loading both tables into a Memory table when performing the work and then copying back to a disc-based table once complete to try and speed up the process, server has 256GB RAM so plenty of room on there. Are there any other settings I can change/tweak?

my.ini is below:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=18G
max_heap_table_size=192G
key_buffer_size=18G
tmp_memory_table_size=64G
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=18G -- too low; raise to 200G
max_heap_table_size=192G    -- dangerously high; set to 2G
key_buffer_size=18G         -- used only by MyISQM; set to 50M
tmp_memory_table_size=64G   -- dangerously high; set to 2G
```

How many rows will be deleted by this?

```
DELETE quick FROM merged
     WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM knownID) ;
```

Change to the "multi-table" syntax for `DELETE` and use `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`

If you are deleting more than, say, a thousand rows, do it in chunks.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

As discussed in that link, it *may* be faster to build a new table with just the rows you want to keep.

`DELETE` must keep the old rows until the end of the statement; then (in the background) do the actual delete.  This is a lot of overhead.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.